# How to mark a file as embedded in VS 2015

Tags: .net, embedded-resource, visual-studio-2015

How do I mark a file as an `Embedded resource` (or similar) in Visual studio 2015? In previous versions you could set the build action. But I cant seem to find it in the properties for the file in VS 2015.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge you can add embedded resources in two ways in Visual Studio 2015:

1. Add the file to compiler\resources in the root of your project
2. Add the file in the project.json file

Example of working custom package.json

In package.json add:

```
 "resource": [
    "Embedded/**/*"
  ]
```

In Visual Studio add the folder "Embedded" with in it add one folder called "Resources" and in it place all your resx-files.

Comment: According to the latest project.json implementation. the "resource" has been deprecated. and you need to add it to the buildOptions.   "buildOptions": {    
    "embed": [ "Embedded/*.resx" ]
  },